# Assets.car contains image multiple times

Tags: xcode, xamarin.ios, assets

I have a Xamarin project and noticed that in my Assets.car the images are contained 6 times but in different formats, as you can see here:

[image: bits]
[image]

E.g. I have an image of 1.8MB in my media.assets, and it blows up into 6 images, with a total size of 15MB.

Can somebody explain this, and is it possible to reduce the size of my Assets.car file?

Comment: Decompress the file and select one format you need , then import the single image file into your project .

Comment: assets.car is generated by Xamarin (or Xcode in a native project) from your assets. My question is why this is generated this way.

Comment: This is by design with apple(iOS) side , maybe you could ask on apple developer forum for better answer  : https://developer.apple.com/forums/.